# Readmore button taking user to top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing problem here . when user clicks read more button then more content is appearing but its taking user to top of the page  , to see a more content the user has to come down the page again .

Can we avoid this ?

Here is my code

```
<!--lot of other content in the page -->
<h1>Example text</h1>
<p >example content.</p><a href="#" onclick="show('example1')"> Read more </a>
<p id="example1" style="display:none; font-weight: bold">more text will appear here.</p>

<script>
 function show(ele){
     document.getElementById(ele).style.display = 'block';   
}
</script>
```

any help

Comment: use preventDefault()

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show('example1');></a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the `href='#'` inside your link, disable the default behavior of it (which would be jump to the location where # exists, the top in this case.

Either apply `return false;` or `e.preventDefault()`

```
<a href="#" onclick="show('example1'); return false;">
```

And a working stack snippet with a large `h1` to illustrate the solution:

```js
function show(ele){
     document.getElementById(ele).style.display = 'block';   
}
```

```css
h1 {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<h1>Example text</h1>
<p >example content.</p><a href="#" onclick="show('example1'); return false;"> Read more </a>
<p id="example1" style="display:none; font-weight: bold">more text will appear here.</p>
```

Comment: will try and let you know